# Datastax Enterprise Edition 4.5 with solr but getting solr timeouts

Tags: solr, datastax-enterprise

We've just upgraded from DataStax Enteprise 3.2.2 to 4.5.1. We migrated from 3.2.2 -> 3.2.5 -> 4.0.3 -> 4.5.1, every time following the procedures in the documentation, and upgrading the sstables after each upgrade.

The servers are running and the core is accepting queries normally.

For some reasone, we're getting with the default configuration of solr/c*/dse  quite often connection timeouts to solr. The queries we're firing are not different that we fired when using DSE 3.2.2 with Solr enabled and there we didn't face those issues.

Did anything changed from 3.2.2 to 4.5 that affects the connectivity of Solr?

the server logs shows:

> ERROR [http-8983-1] 2014-08-01 19:12:52,087 SolrException.java (line 136) null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No response after timeout: 60000
>           at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.shard.netty.NettyShardHandler.waitForResponse(NettyShardHandler.java:115)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.shard.netty.NettyShardHandler.takeCompletedOrError(NettyShardHandler.java:89)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:297)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:137)
>           at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1888)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:723)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.servlet.CassandraDispatchFilter.execute(CassandraDispatchFilter.java:185)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:413)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.servlet.CassandraDispatchFilter.doFilter(CassandraDispatchFilter.java:147)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.audit.SolrHttpAuditLogFilter.doFilter(SolrHttpAuditLogFilter.java:218)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.auth.CassandraAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(CassandraAuthorizationFilter.java:100)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.auth.DseAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DseAuthenticationFilter.java:102)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   ERROR [http-8983-1] 2014-08-01 19:12:52,088 SolrDispatchFilter.java (line 696) Error request exception: No response after timeout: 60000
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No response after timeout: 60000
>           at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.shard.netty.NettyShardHandler.waitForResponse(NettyShardHandler.java:115)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.handler.shard.netty.NettyShardHandler.takeCompletedOrError(NettyShardHandler.java:89)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:297)
>           at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:137)
>           at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1888)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:723)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.servlet.CassandraDispatchFilter.execute(CassandraDispatchFilter.java:185)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:413)
>           at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.servlet.CassandraDispatchFilter.doFilter(CassandraDispatchFilter.java:147)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.cassandra.audit.SolrHttpAuditLogFilter.doFilter(SolrHttpAuditLogFilter.java:218)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.auth.CassandraAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(CassandraAuthorizationFilter.java:100)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at com.datastax.bdp.search.solr.auth.DseAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(DseAuthenticationFilter.java:102)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>           at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>           at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   ERROR [http-8983-1] 2014-08-01 19:12:52,089 SolrDispatchFilter.java (line 697) Error request params: facet=true&facet.mincount=1&q=retailer_id:35788+AND+-ds_product_id:310772487595&facet.limit=10&facet.field=ds_product_id&wt=javabin&version=2&rows=0

Best,
Ramo

Comment: I've changed the dse.yaml from netty to http, restarted the nodes, and it works seamlesly now. with nettys default configuration i've restarted the nodes several times, but always had recurring timeouts when querying the same node but different solr indices in parallel. Are parallel reads on DSE Solr an issue?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any issues, how many concurrent queries did you run and on how many Solr cores? Does anything change if you run queries on just a single core? Are your queries long running?

Keep in mind the default Solr HTTP configuration has no timeout, which is usually a bad thing, and uses the old IO model which spawns several hundred threads, while our Netty configuration has a timeout at 60 seconds and is optimized to use way less threads to reduce footprint, so if your queries are very long running, in the Netty case you have to increase the timeout and possibly increase the number of worker threads.

Comment: I need to investigate on this. We didn't change anything at our query structure after upgrading to 4.5.1. There are some "long running" queries, but via the solr web ui they're never exceeding the 60 seconds. I'm just wondering that the A/B test (DSE 3.2.2 / DSE 4.5.1) failed and that this is with the default configuration from 3.2.2 compatible

Answer (score 0):

Netty has a default timeout of 60 seconds. See *netty_client_request_timeout* in dse.yaml